# Ajax response arrives empty from spring controller, even if it succeeded

Tags: java, ajax, spring, controller

I received empty data from spring controller, even if it returned data the ajax success function received it empty. I tried to return string directly from controller like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestParam("posImsi") String posImsi,@RequestParam("posMsisdn") String posMsisdn){
    return "success";
}
```

and the ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "test",
        type : "POST",
        data : formData,
        beforeSend : function(){
            $("#overlay").show();
        },
        success : function(ajaxResult){
            console.log(ajaxResult);
        },
        complete : function(status) {
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR);
            alert(status);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you include  databind maven dependency in your pom.xml ?

Comment: "Even if it succeeded" - does that mean, a HTTP success code, ...? Maybe better add some response wanted and some response received as code to make it more readable?

Comment: @YasirShabbirChoudhary, yes I did, I used jackson databind

Comment: @Dilettant , I received "200 Http" status when I sent the request

Comment: @Ibrahim try this , hope your problem will be solved .
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

and here is the link which help described difference between RestController vs Controller.
https://www.genuitec.com/spring-frameworkrestcontroller-vs-controller/

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved by using the XMLHttpRequest object to do ajax request, I really don't know what is the difference but here is what I used:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("POST","test",true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.send(formData);
    x.onload = function () {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    };
```

for more information about XMLHttpRequest object: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp